# query to row in coldfusion returning sorted structure

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following function but the function is returning me a structure in sortable format starting from a to z

```
<cffunction name="rowToStruct" access="public" returntype="struct" output="false">
    <cfargument name="queryObj" type="query" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="row" type="numeric" required="true" />
    <cfset var returnStruct = structNew()>
    <cfset var colname = "">
    <cfset cList = arrayToList(arguments.queryObj.getMetaData().getColumnLabels())>
    <cfdump var="#cList#">
    <cfloop list="#cList#" index="colname">
      <cfset "returnStruct.#colname#" = arguments.queryObj[colname][arguments.row]>  
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn returnStruct/>
</cffunction>
```

with above code coming like this

```
BE       Ice
BU       Net
CView     0
CMarketing  0
CProducts   1
CTraining    1
CEProducts   1
Pion     [empty string]
Status   Active
Title    [empty string]
UserType    Mode
Wizard
```

it needs to in like this

```
SELECT TOP 1
        [UserType],
        [Pion],
        [Title],
        [Be],
        [BU],
        [Status],
        [CView],
        [CTraining],
        [CMarketing],
        [CEProducts],
        [CProducts],
        [Wizard]
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: it is returning me a structure but in sorted order, but i want it in the way that it should display in the order in the sql fields are defined, i hope make sense now

Comment: Can you please update your question to include an example of the actual result *and* what it should be instead?

Comment: (Edit) Not sure about the your goal but .. structures are have no guaranteed order.  So the concept of "sorted" is rather meaningless with regular CF structures.  If you are asking how to display query column values in the same order as the SQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354233/returning-the-query-row-with-the-way-the-columns-are-called-in-sql-query/31354451#31354451

Comment: see my comments i have edited those

Comment: Thanks. Like I said above, CF structures *aren't* ordered. That cannot be changed. If you need an ordered result you need to either a) use an array or b) use a java object that does respect order like a [LinkedHashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064461/stop-coldfusion-from-sorting-my-structs-arrays). Since this question was already asked and answered, voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Close it but that does does not work, i checked your gist, but it does not work in coldfusion 10 update 3

Comment: Yes, it does work *if* you use a LinkedHashMap instead of a CF structure. Are you? Also, how are you verifying the result? Do not rely on cfdump. It favours "user friendly" display over accuracy ;-)

Comment: check my comments @leigh, added after the answer by henry

Comment: any one there still yet or gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF as of now (v11) does not have LinkedHashMap, but it's pretty easy to use it.  Just use this `orderedStructNew()` function.

```
/** return <code>java.util.LinkedHashMap</code> that preserves order of insertion */
struct function orderedStructNew()
{
    return createObject("java","java.util.LinkedHashMap").init();
}
```

Then

```
<cfset returnStruct = orderedStructNew()>
<cfset columnLabels = queryObj.getMetaData().getColumnLabels()>
<cfloop array="#columnLabels#" index="local.colname">
  <cfset returnStruct[colname] = queryObj[colname][arguments.row]>
</cfloop>
```

To verify, use `<cfloop collection="#returnStruct#" item="local.key">` and see the keys in the insert order, instead of relying on `<cfdump>`.

Comment: Thanks, cfdump is seriously a shit, but i used the code by @leight, it still gives me wrong order:

Comment: `BD, CView, Wizard, CTraining, BU, CEProducts ,CMarketing, CProducts, UserType ,Status, Position, Title`.  I used this `<cffunction name="rowToStructMaintainedOrder" access="public" returntype="struct" output="false"> <cfargument name="queryObj" type="query" required="true" /> <cfargument name="row" type="numeric" required="true" /><cfset var returnStruct = {}><cfset var col = ""><cfset var colArray = getMetaData(arguments.queryObj)<cfloop array="#colArray#" index="col"><cfset returnStruct[col.Name] = arguments.queryObj[col.Name][arguments.row]></cfloop><cfreturn returnStruct/></cffunction>`

Comment: *but i used the code by @leight*  I did not post code - [just links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064461/stop-coldfusion-from-sorting-my-structs-arrays) ;-).  As I mentioned in the comments, you need to use a LinkedHashMap *instead of* a CF structure. The code you posted is not doing that, which is why it does not work.  See Henry's example above.