# What is the order of struct iteration?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using Coldfusion 10, though I would be interested in answers for any version.

It is known that structs in Coldfusion are not ordered (e.g. [Stop ColdFusion from sorting my structs/arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064461/stop-coldfusion-from-sorting-my-structs-arrays/1064475#1064475)), and that you should not rely on any particular order of iteration. However, the keys are obviously iterated in *some* order, even though it's not sort order or insertion order. Is the order stable and reliable? Is it the order of some underlying Java type?

I should emphasize that I do not intend to rely on this, but I would like to know anyway.

Comment: CF structures used to be implemented as java.util.Hashtable's, but are now an internal/proprietary class coldfusion.util.CaseInsensitiveMap. My guess would be it is similar and that the order is based on [hash value, as with your typical HashMap/Hashtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817695/how-does-java-order-items-in-a-hashmap-or-a-hashtable). I do not think that information would be of any use to you, beyond an intellectual exercise ;-) If you *really* need a "sorted" structure, use one of the available java classes. In most respects they will behave just like a CF structure.

Answer (score 2):

Hashmaps like ColdFusion's struct work with a hash of the key. The hashes are managed in buckets and do not guarantee order over time as the memory address mapping is not linear.

If you need ordered structs in ColdFusion, you can use any Java class that implements the [Map interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and fulfills whatever your requirement is. [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is an example for insertion order. These will work with ColdFusion, but be aware of case sensitivity and a general performance hit.

Regarding best practise: Avoid using ordered structs by using arrays with the ordered keys (remember there is also structSort() in ColdFusion). The only "good" reason to use LinkedHashMap is serializeJSON() when it comes to providing a RESTful service, as order and case sensitivity matter.

Comment: *be aware of case sensitivity* ... and unlike CF, java objects are sometimes type sensitive as well.